# Highlight Row when click and Un-Highlight when click somewhere else

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery and I try to highlight the entire row when user clicks on the cell, it works so far. However, I like to un-highlight that row was selected when user clicks some where else or another row.

Here is my code for highlight the row, but I don't know who to un-highlight it.

```
// Highlight Select Row
$("#mytable td").click(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color','#f00');
    $(this).parent().css("border", "yellow solid 2px"); 
});
```

Please help,
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a class to do it, For example

```
    .highlight
     {
      background-color : #f00 !important;
     }
```

Then in your script

```
     $("#mytable td").click(function() {
        $("#mytable td").removeClass("highlight");
        $(this).addClass("highlight");

     });
```

and where ever you wanna remove highlighting, use

```
      $("#mytable td").removeClass("highlight");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: how do you highlight and un-highlight for the border of entire row like my code example "$(this).parent().css("border", "yellow solid 2px"); "?  Thanks.